# Magento translations

Tags: magento, language-translation

I am having hard time translating Magento to my local language.

I see Magento translations are located under app/locale and I can easily find all the fields in that CSV translation files, but it seems my front end is actually on some part displaying some other text.

When I translate some phrases, most of the stuffs changes, but some text just does not.

Ie on cart page, when I translate part about the coupons

> You have removed the coupon - gets translated 
>   You have applied the coupon - altought translated does not take affect

Pretty strange. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to ask this over at http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: check if your language file is included, the text you want to translate is EXACTLY the same as the text in your CsV. Oh and btw, custom language files usually go in app/design/frontend/themeName/locale

Answer (score 0):

If you need translations for your site but translation packs are not fully translated, then inline translation is very nice feature. You can follow the below steps -

1. Go to Magento admin system > configuration >developer.
   Here from Translate Inline > Enabled for Frontend set to 'Yes'.
2. Go to the frontend and select desired language from the dropdown. Red rectagle strokes around text will apear and when you hover it the little book icon will apear. Just click on the icon and insert desired text.